# How to link libstdc++.so.6 instead of libstdc++.so.5

Tags: linux, ubuntu, redhat

I have a product build on Red Hat, which has both `libstdc++.so.5` and `libstdc++.so.6` in `/usr/lib`.
Now I use this build to run a test on Ubuntu which has only `libstdc++.so.6` in `/usr/lib`, therefore I get the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I tell the compiler on Red Hat to use `libstdc++.so.6` instead of `libstdc++.so.5`?

Comment: what product is it? For which RHEL version is it intended? If that product is Oracle then you can find many Oracle specific HOWTOs on the internet.

Comment: It is a C++ product .It is not intended for any specific version.

Comment: Do you you have sources or .obj files or just a binary? Ver. 5 is very old, AFAIK it was shipped with RHEL4 (or RHEL5). I would also say that ver 6. is not backward compatible, So even if you LP_PRELOAD ver. 6 it will not work anyway - some symbols will be missing. Try to download and unpack some glibc-compat rpm on Ubuntu. Then you will also have to execute `ldd` on your binary and most probably need other referenced old libraries.